# Notepad++ AutoSave issue

Tags: plugins, notepad++

It looks like Notepad++ as of ver. 6.6.7 is now actively blocking the AutoSave (ver. 1.4) plugin.

Notepad++ will remove AutoSave when upgrading and re-loading AutoSave with the Plugin Manager now fails.

Live and die by the ability to make a quick .PHP script change and switch over to the browser window without having to remember to click on the Save file toolbar icon.

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the solution.

Rather than relying on the Autosave version downloaded by Plugin Manager, go to the link listed -- http://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins -- and download v1.40 from there.

The zip file will have 2 versions of the dll (A for ASCII and U for Unicode ?). Copy the AutoSaveU.dll file to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\" and you should be back in business.

**Update:** After running for a few days with Autosave enabled, found that automatic spell check and the ability to right click on a word or phrase would randomly disappear. Disabling "Auto Save when Notepad++ looses focus" solves that problem. For now, have decided that spell check and right clicking are more important than auto-saving.

Comment: A is for what, in Windows, is the ANSI family of character sets. All have an encoding with one byte per character (though most have fewer than 256 characters).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best solution to this, if you install notepad++ and use 'Resource Hacker' (google it) to change the menu (cut it down) and the icon (change to notepad), and install the autosave plugin in notepad++, then you have something that looks almost entirely indistinguishable to classic notepad! And txt files have the notepad logo.

Also you need to go into settings and turn off a bunch of settings, including under editing tab, turn off line numbering, and change colours in 'style configurator'.
The only notable difference is that highlighted text remains black.

Check out this image to see how close it is, you could even cut and rename menu items to look identical but there is no need to be that pedantic.

[image: screenshot]